# External function calling not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, import, external

I was working on a script which could automatically import a navigation bar, when I ran into an error which I can't seem to fix.

HTML:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script scr="http://mySite.nl/navbar.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body onload="onload()">

  <div id="nav-placeholder"></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
function onload() {
 $.get("http://mySite.nl/navbar.html", function(data) {$("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);});
}
```

The navbar HTML file:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="red" href="http://mySite.nl/" id="maintab">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="red" href="http://mySite.nl/#games" id="subtab">Games</a></li>
        <li><a class="red" href="http://mySite.nl/#movies" id="subtab">Movies</a></li>
        <li><a class="red" href="http://mySite.nl/#about" id="subtab">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="blue" href="http://mySite.nl/apps.html" id="maintab">Apps</a></li>
        <li><a class="yellow" href="http://mySite.nl/forum.html" id="maintab">Forum</a></li>
        <li><a class="yellow" href="http://mySite.nl/forum.html#FAQ" id="subtab">Forum</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The error that I get, is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: onload is not defined (index):12
at onload ((index):12)
```

Please help

Comment: 1: spell SRC correctly; 2: onload is possibly a reserved word. 3: Why not use jQuery onload IN the js file: `$(function() {....});` - 4:  never ever do `<body onload="onload()"` - also spell SRC correctly

Comment: Feel free to delete the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am hoping there is no typo here

```
         <script scr="http://mySite.nl/navbar.js"></script>
```

it should be

```
         <script src="http://mySite.nl/navbar.js"></script>
```

otherwise script file will not load

Comment: Thanks, I think I shouldn't be allowed to code anymore due to the insane amount of stupidity on my part...

Comment: But STILL never EVER use body onload. Please just wrap the code in $(function() {  ----  });

Answer (score 0):

onload is an HTML Event Handler. You shouldn't use it as a function name.

But I think, that you haven't load the function.

Edit: Ahh yes. There is an error in the src-Attribute. Therefore it could not be loaded.